# Blank page on AMPPS in Mac OS systems

Tags: php, mysql, apache

The only problem I have been facing using AMPPS is getting blank pages after installation or update sometimes. Other than that is great!
Here is a few hints to deal with that:

Apache:

```
sudo apachectl stop
sudo /Applications/AMPPS/apache/bin/httpd -k start
sudo /Applications/AMPPS/apache/bin/httpd -k restart
```

When MySQL doesn't starts on AMPPS, this might help:

```
1- Open AMPPS Application -> MySQL Tab -> Configuration.  
2- In [mysqld] section, add the following line:   
   innodb_force_recovery = 1  
3- Save the file and try starting MySQL  
4- Remove that line which you just added and Save.
```

or

```
"/Applications/AMPPS/php/bin/php" -c "/Applications/AMPPS/php/etc/php.ini" "/Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/install.php"

"/Applications/AMPPS/php/bin/php" -c "/Applications/AMPPS/php/etc/php.ini" "/Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/cron.php"
```

PhP Errors:

```
1- Go to PhP tab -> PhP Extension
2- Enable those extensions you need for your codes one by one and test it (e.g. mysql.so, mysqli.so, ctype.so, dba.so, pdo_mysql.so)
3- Restart Apache and MySQL
```

Hope someone more knowledgeable would edit this post!
Cheers!